# htaccess redirection from one page to subdomain

Tags: apache2, .htaccess

Mys site has some subdomains (sub1,sub2...etc)
I want to redirect any of my subdomains from one page to another:
from:

```
http://sub1.example.com/dir/page1
```

to

```
https://sub1.example.com/
```

is the below configuration right?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)dir/page1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by Virtual Hosts, see for instance: [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that wasn't my question, I already have virtual hosts configured for mysite, and its subdomains,

but i want a redirection from one page under subdomain to go to the subdomain itself

Comment: @user225844 Ahh, right. Indeed, I think you're on the right track. I can't test from where I'm right now but it looks ok.

Comment: I tested it, and it worked :), thanks for your consideration :)